# Elementary proof for the inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

I have conjectured the following inequality:

> $x+y+z\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$

I have tried to come up with an elementary proof but I failed miserably.

Can Anyone help me, please? Whether the conjecture is true or not?

Comment: The inequality is not valid in general, take $x=y=z=1$

Comment: The following is true for any real numbers: $x+y+z\leq \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

Comment: If $x,y,z \ge 0$ you are basically telling $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}_+^3$ that $\Vert v \Vert_1 \le \Vert v \Vert_2$, which is false.

Comment: @Atticus Well then, also how would one prove it in elementary style?

Comment: @Kumar, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following reasoning is elementary enough.

If $x+y+z<0$ so our inequality is true.

But for $x+y+z\geq0$ it's enough to prove that
$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^2-2xy)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2-2xy+y^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comment, the conjecture suggested by the OP does not hold. However, for any three real number $x,y,z$, we have:

$$x+y+z\leq \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$

It can be proved using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$(1^2+1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$

and thus:

$$\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq |x+y+z| \geq x+y+z$$